# Payara+Jenkins+VisualSVN build successful with no errors, but still not deploying to Payara applications

Tags: jenkins, svn, glassfish, visualsvn-server, payara

1. I have created a simple web application in Netbeans 10.0
2. Integrated successfully with Visual SVN. Regular commits are working fine.
3. Installed Payara 5
4. Installed Jenkins
5. Successfully registered Visual SVN branch in Jenkins job
6. Successfully configured Ant and DEPLOY TO CONTAINER plugins in Jenkins.
7. Registered war filename, Context path, Server Glassfish 3.x, port and hostname in Jenkins
8. Build Now in Jenkins
9. Successful build.
10. Logged into Payara Admin console and clicked Applications
    WHOOOOOSHHHH... No application found there

There is absolutely no error any where. Tried all options including specifying Target/ Arg settings in build.xml
Nothing works.

Please help me as my job is on the stake.

*** P.S.
No where did I find any setting for Payara domain name. That could be a cause but not sure. How would Jenkins know in which Payara domain to deploy the compiled WAR file. May be I am wrong.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: What's in the logs? Any errors?

Comment: Nope. No errors at all

Comment: Can you tell exactly which logs?

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday, I was able to deploy .war on Tomcat successfully. It went straight into webapps.

But the real issue is that when configuring Jenkins with GlassFish, Jenkins doesn't offer an input field for GlassFish Domain. Hence, compilation ends with BUILD SUCCESSFUL and FINISHED messages, but the application could not be seen in any of the Glassfish domains.